# Populating Gridview with DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a gridview that shows details of a table based upon what year is selected in the dropdownlist above the gridview.

The dropdownlist.datasource consists of years in datetime form, and is populated from a Years table (where YearId is the primary key, but not the field that is shown) in the database. The gridview.datasource consists of items from the Items table (where YearId is a foreign key).

When the selection in the dropdownlist is changed, I need to get the selected item's YearId value, and change the datasource of the gridview to be something like this:

```
items.where(item => item.YearId == ((Year)dropdownlist.selecteditem).YearId)
```

Unfortunately, its never this simple, and

```
((Year)dropdownlist.selecteditem).YearId
```

isn't valid. I cannot seem to cast the listitem as a Year object. Any ideas on how to do this?

[EDIT]

Here is how the dropdownlist is populated. If there is a better way of doing this, (and I'm sure there is) feel free to let me know!

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = DataContext.Years;
dropdownlist.DataValueField = "Year";
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Comment: Try casting it from the outside and taking the yearId, and the passing the yearId to the query.

Comment: I'm trying to get the selected item in the dropdownlist as a year (hence the cast on dropdownlist.selecteditem), and then get the YearId value of the Year object. (also, I intended it to be read as pseudocode, just to portray what I want to do)

Comment: Sorry...I need to be clearer. Its not allowing me to perform the cast.

Comment: I meant try doing this `var yearId = ((Year)(drobdownlist.selecteditem)).YearId;` then `items.Where(item => item.YearId == yearId)` or are you getting a TypeCastException?

Comment: that doesn't work. I can't convert type: ListItem to type Year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
dropdownlist.DataSource = DataContext.Years;
dropdownlist.DataValueField = "YearId";
dropdownList.DataTextField = "Year";
dropdownlist.DataBind();
```

Then use bonifaz's query.

Answer (score 2):

Why cast it to a Year at all?
Have you tried this:

```
items.where(item => item.YearId == dropdownlist.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: Because the YearId is different than the Year that is show in the dropdownlist. ie. Year: 2011; YearId: 1

Comment: Yes, and the SelectedValue in the dropdownlist will also be that primary key, i.e., 1, right? If not, please provide us with more information about how your dropdownlist is filled.

Comment: I understand...how I filled the dropdownlist is probably what is preventing this from working. I'll post how I did filled it.